# Simplest way to create a table-based heatmap chart with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coldfusion, d3.js

I've been looking at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), and a few others, and this the closest to what I'm looking for:

- http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084
- http://trends.truliablog.com/vis/tru247/

The tiles would be red, yellow, or green. The data would be server health metrics pulled from a database that's updated in real time. Each tile would represent a server and it's status when the page loaded. The status would likely be a single value such as 100 for good health, and then each error would reduce that value by 5 or something.

I think the hardest part for me is figuring out how to generate the tiles in a webpage efficiently since I'd like to keep this scaleable. I've thought of using ColdFusion and doing a `CFLoop` to create a tile for each server and then javascript to color them according to the database contents. Or just go all out jquery.

Has anyone created a similar "heatmap" of data in a table format like this?

Comment: You could use highcharts too. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/KVn4V/

Comment: I'm not sure why you create tile for each server. Why don't you create your tiles in Javascript?

Comment: I've created a heatmap as part of a bigger thing [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/mpte/). I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency unless you're planning on showing thousands of squares.

Comment: That's helpful Lars, I've been looking into D3 a bit more and found a simple grid: http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2605010 that cleared some questions up. My concern now is tying a unique identifier into each cell that can be used for various UI hover overs. Such as hovering over a cell to view more information on the data behind the scenes. Similar to how you display more info above your heatmap as you hover.